# How to get a function to run twice dynamically

Tags: python, list, function, variables, dynamic

This is a function.

```
def cut_dk():
    a = []; b = []
    random.shuffle(deck__)
    slice = deck__[:2]
    a.append(slice[0])
    b.append(slice[1])
    return a,b

c = cut_dk()
p1 = c[0]
p2 = c[1]
```

I have this function at the top of the program along with other functions.
It draws from a predefined list.
When calling this function dynamically in the program it returns the same variables.
It's the cutting of a card deck (two cards, highest wins the draw), when the cards are equal it needs to draw again (this is the problem, a second draw), a new selection from the list, yet it just repeats the variables it has in memory.

Calling the function again in a conditional statement just returns the same initial variables acquired on the first run, so I am unable to repeat the cut dynamically as part of the game play.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would manage my deck as an `object` here with a `class`. This would allow us to define a deck, which is stored as an object and perform multiple functions against the deck whilst retaining the state changes from different functions.

```
class deck:
    """
        Class designed to manage deck including iterations of changes. 
        Shuffling the deck will retain shuffle changes 
    """
    def __init__(self):
        self.deck = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 'J', 'Q', 'K', 'A']
        self.original = self.deck[:]

    def shuffle(self):
        """
           Shuffle deck in-place. self.deck will be modified
        """
        random.shuffle(self.deck)

    def cut(self):
        """
           Shuffles deck and draws the two top-most cards
           
           Returns: tuple(2) two cards from top of the deck
        """
        self.shuffle()
        a, b = self.deck[:2]
        return a, b

    def highest_draw(self):
        """
           Calls self.cut() to shuffle and retrieve 2x top-most cards. 

           If cards match the deck is shuffled and cut again.

           Returns: 2 Unique cards from top of the deck
        """
        a, b = self.cut()
        while a == b:
            a, b = self.cut()
        return a, b

    def reset(self):
        self.deck = self.original[:]
```

---

```
game = deck()
game.deck
#[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 'J', 'Q', 'K', 'A']

game.shuffle()
game.deck
#['A', 7, 5, 9, 8, 'J', 'K', 6, 4, 3, 1, 'Q', 2]

game.reset()
game.deck
#[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 'J', 'Q', 'K', 'A']

game.cut()
#('A', 'Q')

game.highest_draw()
#('J', 2)
```

You would still need to define how you determine the "highest" card, however this is dependant on your deck, which you have left out of the question.

Comment: This is my deck  [[1, 10, '|    -9-   |   ', '| -Hearts- |   ', '=Red=']] (except it has 24 cards (24 lists), 9 up), a card holds a score for cutting the deck, a score for the game, the cards actual rank, the cards suite and the card color. The scoring of the deck is dependent on a card turned up after the deal (euchre,cut-throat,every man for himself), actually the main issue I have had is cutting the deck, the rest just plays out as a card game, one card follows another until the hand is over... thanks for the comment, it is helpful, I am glad I did not choose "cribbage".

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as if a generator function would be useful here. You call the function once to set up your iterator and then 'draw' cards from that iterator (in this case the iterator is 'cards'). Notice you have to catch the case where you run the whole deck and it's tied throughout. I've sprinkled print statements through this to make it easier to understand how generators work.

```
import random 

deck__ = list(range(3))*2

def draw_from_shuffled():
    random.shuffle(deck__)
    print(f'Deck after shuffling: {deck__}')
    for c in deck__:
        yield c

        
cards = draw_from_shuffled() #cards is now an iterator   
while True:
    try:
        a = next(cards)
        b = next(cards)
    except StopIteration:
        print(f'End of deck!')
        cards = draw_from_shuffled()
        continue
    print(f'Drew {a} and {b}')
    if a != b:
        break
print('Hand done.')
```

Sample output:

```
Deck after shuffling: [2, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0]
Drew 2 and 2
Drew 1 and 1
Drew 0 and 0
End of deck!
Deck after shuffling: [0, 0, 2, 2, 1, 1]
Drew 0 and 0
Drew 2 and 2
Drew 1 and 1
End of deck!
Deck after shuffling: [0, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2]
Drew 0 and 2
Hand done.
```

More on generators: https://realpython.com/introduction-to-python-generators/

Comment: Thanks, very helpful, the actual problem was very simple, I could have easily solved it by a coin toss instead, yet for the game I have always used the deck cutting method for determining the dealer, it also became such a conundrum I was sure it was the coding on my part that needed more attention.